IAPs Failing with "PurchasingUnavailable" when testing on TestFlight
I have no idea what the problem is at this point. I am using Unity Codeless IAP for the game I'm trying to upload to the Apple Store. The app keeps getting rejected for the IAP returning the OnPurchaseFailedFunction. The error message is just the phrase "PurchasingUnavailable." I'm so confused because Unity used to use PurchaseFailedReason and now it's using PurchaseFailedDescription, I uploaded a game before that used OnPurchaseFailedReason and Apple never spat it back saying the purchasing didn't work, because it worked like a charm. However, I can't copy code because it's literally codeless, whatever newer versions Unity brought in or updates Apple made, it's completely ruining my upload process. I can't submit my IAPs for review because even though it says "Ready to Submit," there is NO submit button and it says I have to upload a build with it. All these forums I'm seeing say to get the IAP reviewed and it will start working in TestFlight but how do I even get a build reviewed if the crucial part of it can only get reviewed once the other build works? When I run it in the Unity editor it plays just fine. My bundle identifiers match perfectly between the Apple configuration, XCode, and Unity. My app can't even be run on Sandbox because when I make an account my emails aren't working (that's not the issue here). I know I have no problems with the code because it's supposed to be codeless and I keep getting rejected by Apple with an attached image of my OnPurchaseFailed function. My product IDs match, I can't get much more debugging than the purchaseFailedDescription.reason from Unity and I've spent all day banging my head against the wall at this issue. Attached I have my purchase failed description, the IAP function that I can't submit for review, the rejection message from Apple, my Unity IAPManager function, and lastly my configuration for the IAPButton.
[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/mLSqMvaD.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/26w5kHXM.png)
I've tried turning storeKit on to embed & sign in XCode but that has been making every single one of my archives fail when distributing.
